# How to open a .MSG file which is located in "c:\Test\test.msg"

Tags: vbscript, adsutil.vbs

I need to open a outlook file .MSG in the interval of 1hrs to send report.
the >msg file is a templete which contains Recipients list.pls help me in creating the script

Comment: What did you try by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

With files you can use `set x = GetObject("c:\somefolder\somefile.msg")` to get a reference to a individual object. Use Object browser (Alt + F11 for editor, then F2 for Object Browser) and press F1 for Help..